# How can I access model instance in save_related method of ModelAdmin class?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model with 2 attributes which value depends on related items:

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1, default=0)
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Related items are set as inlines of model in admin page. I want to execute two functions after adding new related items via admin page. When I overwrite save_model method new related items are not saved yet as apparently save_related method executes after save_model

```
class OfferAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Offer
    inlines = [
        CommentInline
    ]

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        obj.rating = get_rating(obj)
        obj.count = get_count(obj)
        obj.save()
```

How can I access object and make changes in model instance in save_related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you are trying to do here is accessing the inline data in the `OfferAdmin`

You can do something like

```
def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
    obj = form.instance
    # make changes to model instance
    obj.save()
    super(OfferAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It worked, thank you so much!  The only thing is that I had to place super() before changes to model instance to make it work post-save