# django admin Inline model is not storing id for related table

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I've combine two models into one in admin panel using `admin.TabularInline` and following is my code that i've tried as far my knowledge.

```
class ProdutImageTabulurInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ProductImage
    exclude = ['user', 'name', 'status']

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ProdutImageTabulurInline
    ]

    # For Do operation before save operation
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        return super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59580458/how-can-i-access-model-instance-in-save-related-method-of-modeladmin-class
    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        obj = form.instance
        obj.user = request.user
        super(ProductAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
```

I've hidden the User field from ProductImages since i want that it should store default user id as logged in user id.

So i used `save_model` for product table and it store user_id as expected
but i want that in products image table too,
and which is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the `save_formset` method instead save_related
My code looks something like this and it works

```
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
    for inline_form in formset.forms:
        inline_form.instance.user = request.user
        inline_form.instance.name = "sample name"
    super().save_formset(request, form, formset, change)
```

- `save_related` :  this is  called once after model save with `save_model`
- `save_formset` :  this will be called many times during each update, once for every inline defined on your ModelAdmin.